# Smoothing video by filtering out single-frame parts in video

Tags: imovie, time-lapse

I have some video material that has been created by time-lapse video using a GoPro Hero 6 Black. Since the camera's position is fixed, the background of the video does not change much. The foreground however changes very fast because of time-lapse. Some objects in the foreground are only visible in one frame.

I need a way to remove the fast-moving parts. If the software detects that a certain part of the video is the same in a few frames, but very different in just one frame, it should replace that part of the single frame by putting the content of the other frames there.

This should result in a smoothening of the whole video.

I don't have access to expensive professional video software. If possible, I need a way to do this in consumer-oriented software like iMovie. I could buy Final Cut Pro if necessary, but would prefer not to.